# Windows Phone 8 Application doesn't run if installed from Market

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have a strange problem. I have a windows phone 8 application, which is successfully installed on the phone under Visual Studio and works. If I deploy my xap using deployment tool it also works. It is successfully submitted on market. But when I download the app on the same phone from market it fails to run. It writes "load....." and that's all.

What may be reason of such behavior?

Comment: Can you provide the download link?

Comment: If you have the visual version of you app already install, it may cause an issue. Maybe you can try to uninstall all version of your app and reinstall only the version from the windows store.

Comment: Of course, I tried it (I mean uninstall and reinstall).

Comment: Igor, the link is available for specified beta-testers only. I shouldn't provide link to app although app doesn't work :-)

Comment: I tried other standard test application (provided by SDK), it's installed from market and runs OK. Manifests of both working and non-working apps are identical. I have really no ideas :(

Comment: was this with _all_ wp8 devices? I'm having a bit similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is a Beta version? or a certified Version?

If it's just a beta version you can create a "logger" for catch all error when you quit your application in

```
App.xaml.cs::Application_UnhandledException
```

and in

```
App.xaml.cs::RootFrame_NavigationFailed
```

this is a sample:

```
private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        // Call your logger class for catch the message exception before application was killed.
        Logger.Debug(e.ExceptionObject.Message);

        if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            // An unhandled exception has occurred; break into the debugger
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        }
     }
```

You juste save the message, or/and  the stackTrace and send you the error by mail.

Also, you can try publish your application on "hidden" on the store.

If the certification team can launch your application, and they're found no error, you can download it with your link. And try to install in your device.
Else, the team found an error, you received a documentation explain why your certification failed...

If it's an Certified Application, I've no Idea for this bug... :'( Maybe you call a invalid server when the application launch or a other error launch an exception?? But It's strange that work with VisualStudio and the .xap deployement...

If you find the solution of your problem, I'm interested :-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The problem was in that I tried to get write access in folder with program (install location)... But why it doesn't notify from Visual Studio or Deployment?! It's yet a puzzle...